# Access 365 bypasses paswords from older databases

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016, ms-access-2003

I recently updated some computers from XP->Windows 10 and from Office 4.3->Office 365.
My concern is that Office 365 Access bypasses passwords on the database files created with Office 4.3 Acess, and I don't know why. 
The files are stored on a local server, multiple persons having access to them, but only the people with the password can read information from them, so it creates a security issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Support for *user-level security* was removed for the new database format, *accdb*:

[What happened to user-level security?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-happened-to-user-level-security-69b362cd-503f-4e8a-a735-fb923ffb9fa3)

Answer (score 0):

"older"... Office 4.3 is from 1994 and had Access 2.0.
I'm surprised you can even connect to this format with Office 365.

The password encryption was changed with Access 2007/2010 and the .accdb format, to now being actually useful and secure.

If you want to keep password encryption, I think you have no choice but to upgrade all clients and the backend.